# Internationalization of a VB 6 Application

Tags: vb6, internationalization

Has anyone internationalized a VB 6 application?
Any helpful resources or tips/tricks you can offer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Get hold of [Michael Kaplan](http://blogs.msdn.com/michkap/)'s book [Internationalization With Visual Basic](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Internationalization-Visual-Basic-Michael-Kaplan/dp/0672319772) (maybe [secondhand](http://www.abebooks.com/servlet/SearchResults?an=kaplan&sts=t&tn=Internationalization+With+Visual+Basic)). It's a goldmine of useful information. I have some peeves with the editing - the index is awful and the chapter order is a bit random - but it's still excellent. There are some free [sample chapters](http://www.i18nwithvb.com/chapters/) on the book's website.

If you are not already familiar with *Unimess* - the appalling mishmash that is VB6 Unicode support - do read [Chapter 6](http://www.i18nwithvb.com/chapters/Chapter06_en.htm) which is one of the free chapters. Cyberactivex.com also has a good [tutorial](http://www.cyberactivex.com/UnicodeTutorialVb.htm) on the subject.

Finally, do read the [International Issues](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa242115(VS.60).aspx) section in the VB6 manual. It's not exhaustive but it's worth reading.

EDIT: see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/898/internationalization-in-your-projects/1462#1462) for a programming-language neutral discussion of internationalisation - nearly all relevant to VB6. VB6 [Format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa262745(VS.60).aspx) function is useful for regionally aware display of numbers, currencies, dates and times. [CDbl, CDate etc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa263426(VS.60).aspx) are useful for converting back from strings to the intrinsic types.