# How to Globalize Visual Basic 6.0 Application?

Tags: vb6, localization, internationalization, globalization

In VB6, can you achieve globalization?
If yes, then how?

My application is currently written in VB6.0 and there is no chance to migrate it to .Net.
I would like to know that how to globalize it.

For example, is there any way to show the date according to time zone (obtained from database/ini file)?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "achieve globalization"? Do you want to display a `DateTime` value according to the current user's localization settings?

Comment: @Cody Gray, Thats exactly what I need. I would like to display a DateTime value according to the current user's localization settings....but in VB6...as my company denied to migrate to .net. So having no choice but to do the same in VB6

Comment: @Cody Gray, would like to add more here, Localization settings is retrieved from Database (not from local system / server). So cannot use Local system's / Server's TimeZone settings. So can you help me out to display DateTime value according to the Localization settings available in database. (here, while replying forget about database connection and table structure). Also I had been given authority to change the column value(in database) accordingly, if needed. so if you think I should get a specific information from database then it can be done from my end.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Internationalization of a VB 6 Application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/830367/internationalization-of-a-vb-6-application)

Comment: @Cody I don't think we should close this question. This question is interesting and not a duplicate: "how can I show the date according to a time zone obtained from a database/INI file, which is different from the local system settings". I agree the introductory part makes it sound like a duplicate: "how to globalize Visual Basic 6.0 application"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/830367/internationalization-of-a-vb-6-application/830533#830533) to similar question.

It links to some book, which is probably what you don't want, but tough luck.
BTW. If you don't care much about Localization for now, you may want to [search web on VB6 Internationalization](http://www.google.com/search?q=visual%20basic%206%20internationalization). You surely find some content, but as VB6 is pretty ancient, not much buzz is going on this topic.

Comment: +1. For linking to my answer ;) Yep, I linked to "some book" - Michael Kaplan's book [Internationalization With Visual Basic](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Internationalization-Visual-Basic-Michael-Kaplan/dp/0672319772). It really is the best source of information on VB6 internationalisation. I also linked to the [VB6 manual](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa242115%28VS.60%29.aspx). I recommend reading the manual before you Google randomly. If you are serious about VB6 localization, I do recommend the book. [MichKap](http://blogs.msdn.com/michkap/) is an internationalisation legend.

Comment: @MarkJ: I didn't know you'd already answered this question conclusively. Totally agreed about MichKap being the expert on internalization. I think this question definitely counts as a duplicate. I've added my vote to close.

Comment: @Cody: Globalization != Internationalization. In fact, Globalization = Internationalization + Localization. Therefore it is not a duplicate, although very similar.

Comment: Erm... In typical usage, all those terms mean exactly the same thing. I don't really know that I agree with the meaning that you're assigning to them. I agree that localization is different, but "international" and "global" mean the same thing. I specifically asked the OP what he wanted to accomplish, and it looks like the same thing to me. Not to mention the fact that your answer consists almost entirely of a reference to an answer to the other question. I'm hard pressed to see how it's anything *but* a duplicate.

Comment: @Cody @Pawel Internationalization is different from localization. [Wikipedia says](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internationalization_and_localization) that "some companies use globalization as  "internationalization + localization". I had not come across this usage of globalization before.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend checking out the [UniSuitePlus](http://www.cyberactivex.com/) product by CyberActiveX. It provides a complete replacement for the default VB6 controls and fully supports unicode.

As a side bonus, when using it with a manifest, it will also provide your app with a modern look in controls like ListView, which retain the classic (old) look in default VB6, even when using a manifest.

Comment: Powerful stuff, but it doesn't help display a Date formatted to a specific locale, which was the specific problem in the question.