# Obtaining the equivalent to printf or String.Format in Excel

Tags: excel

I seem to spend a large amount of my time in spreadsheets working on formulas like:

```
="some text '" & A1 & "', more text: '" & A2 &" etc."
```

It would be much quicker to use a printf or String.Format string like

```
=String.Format ("Some text '{0}', more text: '{1}'",A1,A2)
```

Is there anything like this built in to Excel, or can I call out to CLR?

Comment: There's a plugin for that: http://seotoolsforexcel.com/format/

Comment: For others finding this from Google: A deleted answer by @PMBottas links to [this VB `sprintf()`](http://www.freevbcode.com/ShowCode.asp?ID=5014) ([Wayback direct code link](https://web.archive.org/web/20170914101712/http://www.freevbcode.com/imagesvr_ce/184390/source/printf.zip)), which worked for me.  I imported the included `printf.bas` into a Word VBA project and was able to use the `SPrintF` function without trouble.  I was also able to use it from Excel, e.g., `=sprintf("Hello, %s!","World")`.

Answer (score 93, accepted):

No, but you can create a naive one simply enough by adding the following to a VBA module:

```vb
Public Function printf(ByVal mask As String, ParamArray tokens()) As String
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 0 To ubound(tokens)
        mask = replace$(mask, "{" & i & "}", tokens(i))
    Next
    printf = mask
End Function
```

...

```vb
=printf("Some text '{0}', more text: '{1}'", A1, A2)
```

Comment: Keep in mind that this is unsafe for instances where one of your replaced tokens may contain another placeholder. (Where `A1` is equal to `'test {1}'` for instance.

Comment: Marius is right, to make it bullet-proof you could escape `{` and `}` in the tokens array before the replacement, and afterwards unescape them (for example, replace `{` by `{*` and `}` by `*}`, then run the `for` loop, and afterwards replace `{*` and `*}` back to `{` and `}` before you return the string).

Comment: Another thing - since this has more similarities to `String.Format` in .NET, why not name it `StrFormat`? Reason is, below we can find another answer where the C-style printf is implemented from your code  ...

Comment: You may want `mask` to be passed by value, e.g. `ByVal mask As String`

Comment: @Marius & Matt - implemented the "Bullet Proof" version, as well as the ability to leave out the index: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67858844/6609896

Comment: With the new Excel LAMBDA function this answer is IMO outdated - the VBA still works but you can now create an equivalent without VBA (see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69266041/6609896))

Answer (score 22):

Not really - there is the [CONCATENATE](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/concatenate-function-8f8ae884-2ca8-4f7a-b093-75d702bea31d) function:

```
=CONCATENATE("some text '", A1, "', more text: '", A2, " etc.")
```

But it's no better than using `&` in my opinion.

Comment: Thanks. Thats slightly better as you can see which argument you're in as you type, and I think it will handle errors better.

Comment: Also it prevents you from having to deal in ugly ways with quotation marks in strings.

Comment: There's also a character limit on formulas that gets frustrating with this approach... I end up creating a set of columns that are all the text... and then concatenating all the text cells with data cells to get around this issue.

Comment: this is the most elegant solution imo without requiring VBA code/macros

Answer (score 15):

I've updated Alex's code so you can use `%s` for each insertion.

Instead of:

```vb
=printf("Some text '{0}', more text: '{1}'", A1, A2)
```

You can use:

```vb
=printf("Some text '%s', more text: '%s'", A1, A2)
```

Just like the original `sprintf`.

The updated code:

```vb
Public Function Printf(ByVal mask As String, ParamArray tokens()) As String
   Dim i As Long

   For i = 0 To UBound(tokens)          
      mask = Replace$(mask, "%s", tokens(i), , 1)
   Next

   Printf = mask

End Function
```

Comment: Yes, looks like original printf indeed. But what Marius has mentioned in the original answer is also true here: It is unsafe for instances where the **tokens** array contains another placeholder - for example `"test %s"`. In the comments above I made a suggestion how to remediate this issue.

Answer (score 13):

You can use the TEXT function -

You can store your format string somewhere in a cell like I did.

I have value of `"BUY "#" CREDITS"` in my D1 cell.
In my A5 cell I have a value of 5000.
When I want to display the formatted string I use `=TEXT(A5, $D$1)`.

It will set the value of cell to BUY 5000 CREDITS.

Comment: Note that this method only works with one token, i.e., you can't do `"I bought "#" Apples and "#" Oranges."`. I was hoping for something like `String.Format("I bought {0} apples and {1} oranges.", <Cell1>, <Cell2>)` but this method can't do that. (I'm trying to avoid VBA)

Answer (score 3):

"Bullet proof" version of the one provided by [@AlexK](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17233834/6609896), allowing for:

- Escaped tokens `printf("{0}{1}", "test {1}", 2) -> "test {1}2" (NOT "test 22")`
- Positional syntax `printf("{}{}", "a", "b") -> "ab"`

```vb
Public Function printf(ByVal mask As String, ParamArray tokens() As Variant) As String
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 0 To UBound(tokens)
        Dim escapedToken As String
        escapedToken = Replace$(tokens(i), "}", "\}") 'only need to replace closing bracket since {i\} is already invalid
        If InStr(1, mask, "{}") <> 0 Then
            'use positional mode {}
            mask = Replace$(mask, "{}", escapedToken, Count:=1)
         
        Else
            'use indexed mode {i}
            mask = Replace$(mask, "{" & i & "}", escapedToken)
        
        End If
    Next
    mask = Replace$(mask, "\}", "}")
    printf = mask
End Function
```

Usage as before:

```vb
=printf("Some text '{0}', more text: '{1}'", A1, A2)
```

OR positional (left to right)

```vb
=printf("Some text '{}', more text: '{}'", A1, A2)
```

*Note as @CristianBuse points out in the comments, this implementation will still be tripped up by a mask like `{0\}{1}` which results in `{0}{foo}` not `{0\}{foo}`, workaround is don't use `\}` in your mask.*

---

<sub>*behaviour using mixed syntax `=printf("Some text '{}', more text: '{1}'", A1, A2)` is undefined but the replacements go left to right so `"{}{2}{1}"` is equivalent to `"{0}{2}{1}"`. `"{}{1}{}"` won't do what you want</sub>

Comment: Maybe you should make an initial replacement before the loop to replace ```"\}``` with something else and then restore before returning the result just to avoid cases where the mask already contains those characters in that particular order. An example would be a mask like ```"{0\}{1}"``` which should return the ```{0\}``` part as is instead of ```{0}``` as your method does. +1

Comment: @CristianBuse yeah I was thinking about exactly that earlier except, what if the thing I replace `\}` with is itself in the mask, then when you restore it you get two `\}` back. Could replace with something really long like a GUID to avoid clashes, or closely monitor what happens to Len() and insert characters into the string at particular locations, but really that becomes a better job for regex or just use [Matt's version](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14534361/6609896) so I kept it simple, this suffices for my purposes. But good catch, **a mask containing `\}` is indeed a buggy edge case**

Comment: Funny that you mentioned it because I was thinking of the same thing. What if the "temp" replacement is actually part of the mask, then you add another "temp" which can be part of the tokens which can then be part of the mask. It never ends really. I was also thinking to traverse/parse the whole mask and then "replace" at particular locations via concatenation (no call to ```Replace```). Thanks for the link, I will have a look although regex is very slow in VBA even for simple patterns (could be thousands of times slower).

Answer (score 3):

Ok I gave a [VBA solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67858844/6609896) but here's a pure Excel version using the relatively new LAMBDA functions, *no VBA*.

---

<sub>*Note I've posted an [alternate version](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/268446/146810) with comma separated args `PRINTF(mask, arg1, arg2, ...)` over on Code Review, however I'll try to keep this one canonical and up to date as new better options become available*</sub>

---

To achieve this I have created a named function with signature `printf(mask, tokensArray)` where:

- `mask` is a string you want to format, containing positional `{}` or indexed `{i}` interpolation locations.
- `tokensArray` is the set of values to be substituted in, supplied as either a 1D Range (row or column), an array (hardcoded or returned from a function) or a single value.

... and which returns a formatted string. Called from a cell like:

[image: Tooltip]

[image: Usage]

```swift
=printf("Some text '{1}', more text: '{2}'", A1:A2) //continuous 1D row/col
=printf("Some text '{1}', more text: '{2}'", {"foo","bar"}) //hardcoded array
=printf("Single Value {1}", "foo")
```

or with positional args (left to right)

```swift
=printf("Some text '{}', more text: '{}'", A1:A2)
```

---

Define these two functions by entering them in the name manager (see [LAMBDA function](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/lambda-function-bd212d27-1cd1-4321-a34a-ccbf254b8b67) MSDN docs for detailed instructions, though this link will die I'm sure...) :

| Param | Value |
| --- | --- |
| Name | ReplaceRecursive |
| Scope | Workbook |
| Comment | Recursively substitutes {} or {i} with tokens from the tokens list, which it escapes one by one leaving } in the result string |
| Refers To | `=LAMBDA(mask,tokens,i,tokenCount, IF(i >tokenCount, mask, LET(token, INDEX(tokens,i),escapedToken,SUBSTITUTE(token,"}", "\}"),inIndexedMode,ISERROR(FIND("{}",mask,1)),substituted, IF(inIndexedMode, SUBSTITUTE(mask,"{"&i&"}", escapedToken),SUBSTITUTE(mask, "{}", escapedToken,1) ),ReplaceRecursive(substituted,tokens,i+1,tokenCount))))` |

```swift
=LAMBDA(
    mask,
    tokens,
    i,
    tokenCount,
    IF(
        i > tokenCount,
        mask,
        LET(
            token,
            INDEX(
                tokens,
                i
            ),
            escapedToken,
            SUBSTITUTE(
                token,
                "}",
                "\}"
            ),
            inIndexedMode,
            ISERROR(
                FIND(
                    "{}",
                    mask,
                    1
                )
            ),
            substituted,
            IF(
                inIndexedMode,
                SUBSTITUTE(
                    mask,
                    "{" & i & "}",
                    escapedToken
                ),
                SUBSTITUTE(
                    mask,
                    "{}",
                    escapedToken,
                    1
                )
            ),
            ReplaceRecursive(
                substituted,
                tokens,
                i + 1,
                tokenCount
            )
        )
    )
)
```

| Param | Value |
| --- | --- |
| Name | printf |
| Scope | Workbook |
| Comment | printf(mask: str, tokensArray: {array,} | range | str ) -> str | mask: string to substitute tokens into e.g. "Hello {}, {}" or "Hello {2}, {1}" (1-indexed) | tokensArray: 1D range or array of tokens, e.g. "world" or {"foo","bar"} or A1:A5 |
| Refers To | `=LAMBDA(mask,tokensArray,LET(r,ROWS(tokensArray), c, COLUMNS(tokensArray), length, MAX(r,c), IF(AND(r>1, c>1), "tokensArray must be 1 dimensional", SUBSTITUTE(ReplaceRecursive(mask, tokensArray, 1, length), "\}","}"))))` |

```swift
=LAMBDA(
    mask,
    tokensArray,
    LET(
        r,
        ROWS(
            tokensArray
        ),
        c,
        COLUMNS(
            tokensArray
        ),
        length,
        MAX(
            r,
            c
        ),
        IF(
            AND(
                r > 1,
                c > 1
            ),
            "tokensArray must be 1 dimensional",
            SUBSTITUTE(
                ReplaceRecursive(
                    mask,
                    tokensArray,
                    1,
                    length
                ),
                "\}",
                "}"
            )
        )
    )
)
```

---

There will be improvements to Excel's LAMBDA functions that make this easier to write I'm sure, but this recursive approach is good for now I think.

Answer (score 2):

Interesting question... I was thinking the same.. how to build a String without having to cut off long sentence in some single parts between Numbers.

And because I don't want to create a VBA function (which will be much smarter), here is my solution...

```vb
SUBSTITUTE(P253;O252;"A1A";1)
```

where

- P253 is my long string with "A1A" for #1 label
- O252 is the Value of #1 label

And so on... (even if not my need) if other values...

```vb
=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(P253;O251;"A1A";1);O252;"A2A";1);O253;"A2A";1)
```

Well, I presume, even in #C, there should be multi substitution primitive function for sprintf(....%s, %s, %d..).

Answer (score 0):

Credit as per comment on second line

```
Public Function printf(ByVal strText As String, ParamArray PassedArgs()) As String
' © codekabinett.com - You may use, modify, copy, distribute this code as long as this line remains

    Dim i           As Integer
    Dim strRetVal   As String
    Dim startPos    As Integer
    Dim endPos      As Integer
    Dim formatString As String
    Dim argValueLen As Integer
    Dim Args() As Variant
    
    strRetVal = strText
    
    'Block added to allow for ParamArray to be passed through multiple functions
    If IsArray(PassedArgs(0)) Then
        Args = PassedArgs(0)
    Else
        Args = PassedArgs
    End If
    'End block
    
    For i = LBound(Args) To UBound(Args)
        argValueLen = Len(CStr(i))
        startPos = InStr(strRetVal, "{" & CStr(i) & ":")
        If startPos > 0 Then
            endPos = InStr(startPos + 1, strRetVal, "}")
            formatString = Mid(strRetVal, startPos + 2 + argValueLen, endPos - (startPos + 2 + argValueLen))
            strRetVal = Mid(strRetVal, 1, startPos - 1) & Format(Args(i), formatString) & Mid(strRetVal, endPos + 1)
        Else
            strRetVal = Replace(strRetVal, "{" & CStr(i) & "}", Args(i))
        End If
    Next i

    printf = strRetVal
End Function
```