# Is there any C-style string formatting in VBA?

Tags: vba, string, format, c-strings

I would like to use C-style string formatting in VBA to make it easier to send SQL instructions the same way I do in Python.

Is there anything similar?

```py
sql = "INSERT INTO customers (name, address) VALUES (%s, %s)"
val = ("John", "Highway 21")
mycursor.execute(sql, val)
```

Thank you,

Comment: I found this, it helped me https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17233701/is-there-an-equivalent-of-printf-or-string-format-in-excel

Comment: In that case it's a good option to answer your own question, or to close this question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a System.Text.StringBuilder like this:

```
Function FormatString(Text As String, ParamArray Args() As Variant) As String
    Dim values()
    Dim n As Long
    ReDim values(UBound(Args))

    For n = 0 To UBound(Args)
        values(n) = Args(n)
    Next

    With CreateObject("System.Text.StringBuilder")
        .AppendFormat_4 Text, values
        FormatString = .toString
    End With
End Function
```

### Test

[image: Immediate Window Screenshot]
You can find a class that I wrote to wrap the System.Text.StringBuilder here: [Bringing The System.Text.StringBuilder Up To Lightning Speed In The VBA](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/196076/171419).

Answer (score 0):

I found this, it helped me, is a similar way:

[Is there an equivalent of printf or String.Format in Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17233701/is-there-an-equivalent-of-printf-or-string-format-in-excel)

```vb
Public Function printf(mask As String, ParamArray tokens()) as String

    Dim i as Long
    For i = 0 To Ubound(tokens)
        mask = replace$(mask, "{" & i & "}", tokens(i))
    Next

    printf = mask

End Function
```

```vb
myString = printf("Some text '{0}', more text: '{1}'", A1, A2)
```