# Excel function to construct an array from values without VBA

Tags: excel, vba, lambda, excel-formula, dynamic-arrays

*NB This question refers to some features like optional LAMBDA       arguments and the ISOMITTED function which are only available (at the time of writing) in the Beta channel (more info [here](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/excel-blog/announcing-lambda-helper-functions-lambdas-as-arguments-and-more/ba-p/2576648))*

---

I am trying to mimic VBA's paramarray in an Excel LAMBDA function, so would like a function:

```swift
=ARRAY(arg_1, [arg_2], [arg_3], ...)
```

...which returns the array `{arg_1, arg_2, arg_3, ...}` dynamically sized according to however many args were passed.

If I know the number of args, I can just use the choose function like this:

```swift
=CHOOSE(SEQUENCE(number_of_args), arg_1, arg_2, arg_3, ...))
```

But I don't want to pass the number of arguments as a parameter, I want that to be dynamic. One idea was to do a binary search with `ISOMITTED(arg_n)` to find the first missing argument. But that still hardcodes an upper limit on number of args to my ARRAY function, not to mention creating a nasty binary tree hardcoded.

---

This is of course easy with vba:

```vb
Public Function ARRAYFROMARGS(ParamArray args()) As Variant
    ARRAYFROMARGS = args
End Function
```

[image: demo of calling ARRAYFROMARGS]

Although this can only accept values which can be coerced into Variants so not lambdas or linked data types for example. This makes the non-VBA version more flexible.

Comment: Where is the input coming from, will it be a cell that has the arguments in a string?  Or are you going to hard code the arguments in the formula?

Comment: @ScottCraner Not hardcoded, otherwise `={1,2,3}` works. I want `={A1,A5,B4,"foo",Bar"}` type of thing. I was hoping to avoid manually parsing a stringified version because that would require escaping all the arguments, and some datatypes can't be faithfully stringified

Comment: @ScottCraner oh I think I misinterpreted your question. I will be calling the function like this `=PRINTF("Some text {1}, more text {2}", ARRAY("foo",  A1))` where `ARRAY` takes a variable number of arguments and wraps them into an array to pass to PRINTF which expects only two args; a string mask, and a dynamic array of tokens like [this example function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69266041/6609896) does. Does that clarify?

Comment: I understood.  My research says it is not possible with lambda. Lambda requires a set number of inputs. The last input can be an array but it must be entered as a normal array, which brings back the choose to create the array. I am hoping I am wrong and will lurk on this question to see if there any that know better than I.

Comment: @ScottCraner well I've given the brute force approach, although it is somewhat optimised to have `O(log n)` rather than `O(n/2)` complexity, so it runs pretty fast. Now you can make an ARRAY out of anything:) But hopefully someone can see an improvement somewhere

Comment: I'm probably missing something...can you pass the value as a JSON array, then parse, or use a range reference instead?

Comment: @RyanWildry not really no, a range reference is what I started with but it's not great because sometimes you don't want intermediate calculation cells, especially ones which exist solely to put the arguments in a contiguous range rather than spread out. JSON / another encoding won't work because some data types are not stringifiable like LAMBDA objects or linked data types and I want to make arrays of those too. Besides how would you dynamically construct the JSON, using something like PRINTF surely, so chicken and egg situation

Comment: Don't dispose of Lamba()-function reserved to [*Office insiders*](https://products.office.com/en-us/office-insider), but what about [`MakeArray()`](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/makearray-function-b80da5ad-b338-4149-a523-5b221da09097)?

Answer (score 2):

Well as I alluded to in the question, I've found a way to use a binary search to evaluate how many arguments are missing. It does involve a lot of copy-paste though. So here's code to evaluate the number of args passed by finding the first which is missing:

| Tag | Value |
| --- | --- |
| Name | ARGSCOUNT |
| Scope | Workbook |
| Comment | Use a hardcoded binary search to find the first omitted argument, in chunks of up to 63 |
| Refers To | `=LAMBDA([p_1],[p_2],[p_3],[p_4],[p_5],[p_6],[p_7],[p_8],[p_9],[p_10],[p_11],[p_12],[p_13],[p_14],[p_15],[p_16],[p_17],[p_18],[p_19],[p_20],[p_21],[p_22],[p_23],[p_24],[p_25],[p_26],[p_27],[p_28],[p_29],[p_30],[p_31],[p_32],[p_33],[p_34],[p_35],[p_36],[p_37],[p_38],[p_39],[p_40],[p_41],[p_42],[p_43],[p_44],[p_45],[p_46],[p_47],[p_48],[p_49],[p_50],[p_51],[p_52],[p_53],[p_54],[p_55],[p_56],[p_57],[p_58],[p_59],[p_60],[p_61],[p_62],[p_63],IF(ISOMITTED(p_32),IF(ISOMITTED(p_16),IF(ISOMITTED(p_8),IF(ISOMITTED(p_4),IF(ISOMITTED(p_2),IF(ISOMITTED(p_1),0,1),IF(ISOMITTED(p_3),2,3)),IF(ISOMITTED(p_6),IF(ISOMITTED(p_5),4,5),IF(ISOMITTED(p_7),6,7))),IF(ISOMITTED(p_12),IF(ISOMITTED(p_10),IF(ISOMITTED(p_9),8,9),IF(ISOMITTED(p_11),10,11)),IF(ISOMITTED(p_14),IF(ISOMITTED(p_13),12,13),IF(ISOMITTED(p_15),14,15)))),IF(ISOMITTED(p_24),IF(ISOMITTED(p_20),IF(ISOMITTED(p_18),IF(ISOMITTED(p_17),16,17),IF(ISOMITTED(p_19),18,19)),IF(ISOMITTED(p_22),IF(ISOMITTED(p_21),20,21),IF(ISOMITTED(p_23),22,23))),IF(ISOMITTED(p_28),IF(ISOMITTED(p_26),IF(ISOMITTED(p_25),24,25),IF(ISOMITTED(p_27),26,27)),IF(ISOMITTED(p_30),IF(ISOMITTED(p_29),28,29),IF(ISOMITTED(p_31),30,31))))),IF(ISOMITTED(p_48),IF(ISOMITTED(p_40),IF(ISOMITTED(p_36),IF(ISOMITTED(p_34),IF(ISOMITTED(p_33),32,33),IF(ISOMITTED(p_35),34,35)),IF(ISOMITTED(p_38),IF(ISOMITTED(p_37),36,37),IF(ISOMITTED(p_39),38,39))),IF(ISOMITTED(p_44),IF(ISOMITTED(p_42),IF(ISOMITTED(p_41),40,41),IF(ISOMITTED(p_43),42,43)),IF(ISOMITTED(p_46),IF(ISOMITTED(p_45),44,45),IF(ISOMITTED(p_47),46,47)))),IF(ISOMITTED(p_56),IF(ISOMITTED(p_52),IF(ISOMITTED(p_50),IF(ISOMITTED(p_49),48,49),IF(ISOMITTED(p_51),50,51)),IF(ISOMITTED(p_54),IF(ISOMITTED(p_53),52,53),IF(ISOMITTED(p_55),54,55))),IF(ISOMITTED(p_60),IF(ISOMITTED(p_58),IF(ISOMITTED(p_57),56,57),IF(ISOMITTED(p_59),58,59)),IF(ISOMITTED(p_62),IF(ISOMITTED(p_61),60,61),IF(ISOMITTED(p_63),62,63)))))))` |

<sub>*Easier to copy versions [here](https://gist.github.com/Greedquest/d06b8e79059df4fc88d85f5e320d3ec1)*</sub>

It is called like this `=ARGSCOUNT(arg_1, arg_2, ..., arg_63)` from an enclosing LAMBDA. Note it takes up to 63 optional arguments because my binary tree is symmetrical so must be a power of 2 (minus 1 for the case of 0 arguments) and named references have a low character limit around 2000. However you can call it more than once from a parent function and sum the result e.g. `ARGSCOUNT(arg_1, ..., arg_63) + ARGSCOUNT(arg_64, ..., arg_126)`

Then that count can be used in a second LAMBDA function to build the array:

| Tag | Value |
| --- | --- |
| Name | ARRAY |
| Scope | Workbook |
| Comment | Create an array from comma separated arguments, up to 130 |
| Refers To | `=LAMBDA(_0,[_1],[_2],[_3],[_4],[_5],[_6],[_7],[_8],[_9],[_10],[_11],[_12],[_13],[_14],[_15],[_16],[_17],[_18],[_19],[_20],[_21],[_22],[_23],[_24],[_25],[_26],[_27],[_28],[_29],[_30],[_31],[_32],[_33],[_34],[_35],[_36],[_37],[_38],[_39],[_40],[_41],[_42],[_43],[_44],[_45],[_46],[_47],[_48],[_49],[_50],[_51],[_52],[_53],[_54],[_55],[_56],[_57],[_58],[_59],[_60],[_61],[_62],[_63],[_64],[_65],[_66],[_67],[_68],[_69],[_70],[_71],[_72],[_73],[_74],[_75],[_76],[_77],[_78],[_79],[_80],[_81],[_82],[_83],[_84],[_85],[_86],[_87],[_88],[_89],[_90],[_91],[_92],[_93],[_94],[_95],[_96],[_97],[_98],[_99],[_100],[_101],[_102],[_103],[_104],[_105],[_106],[_107],[_108],[_109],[_110],[_111],[_112],[_113],[_114],[_115],[_116],[_117],[_118],[_119],[_120],[_121],[_122],[_123],[_124],[_125],[_126],[_127],[_128],[_129],CHOOSE(SEQUENCE(ARGSCOUNT(_1,_2,_3,_4,_5,_6,_7,_8,_9,_10,_11,_12,_13,_14,_15,_16,_17,_18,_19,_20,_21,_22,_23,_24,_25,_26,_27,_28,_29,_30,_31,_32,_33,_34,_35,_36,_37,_38,_39,_40,_41,_42,_43,_44,_45,_46,_47,_48,_49,_50,_51,_52,_53,_54,_55,_56,_57,_58,_59,_60,_61,_62,_63)+ARGSCOUNT(_64,_65,_66,_67,_68,_69,_70,_71,_72,_73,_74,_75,_76,_77,_78,_79,_80,_81,_82,_83,_84,_85,_86,_87,_88,_89,_90,_91,_92,_93,_94,_95,_96,_97,_98,_99,_100,_101,_102,_103,_104,_105,_106,_107,_108,_109,_110,_111,_112,_113,_114,_115,_116,_117,_118,_119,_120,_121,_122,_123,_124,_125,_126)+ARGSCOUNT(_127,_128,_129)+1),_0,_1,_2,_3,_4,_5,_6,_7,_8,_9,_10,_11,_12,_13,_14,_15,_16,_17,_18,_19,_20,_21,_22,_23,_24,_25,_26,_27,_28,_29,_30,_31,_32,_33,_34,_35,_36,_37,_38,_39,_40,_41,_42,_43,_44,_45,_46,_47,_48,_49,_50,_51,_52,_53,_54,_55,_56,_57,_58,_59,_60,_61,_62,_63,_64,_65,_66,_67,_68,_69,_70,_71,_72,_73,_74,_75,_76,_77,_78,_79,_80,_81,_82,_83,_84,_85,_86,_87,_88,_89,_90,_91,_92,_93,_94,_95,_96,_97,_98,_99,_100,_101,_102,_103,_104,_105,_106,_107,_108,_109,_110,_111,_112,_113,_114,_115,_116,_117,_118,_119,_120,_121,_122,_123,_124,_125,_126,_127,_128,_129))` |

---

Nasty I know, but that gives you access to a surprisingly simple function:

```swift
=ARRAY(A1, A2, 3, "foo", "bar") // array of anything, dynamically sized
```

[image: ARRAY function]

---

#### BONUS:

You can even create an array of LAMBDAS to pass to something like map:

```swift
=MAP(ARRAY(LAMBDA(x, x^2), LAMBDA(y, y+1)),LAMBDA(f, f(3)) // -> {9,4} i.e. 3^2, 3+1
```

... and the vba ARRAYFROMARGS func can't take LAMBDAS as arguments.

Answer (score 2):

This isn't exactly what you're looking for, but maybe it will give some ideas? If we can take values one at a time as opposed to a list, then rather than having a limit on parameters, we can have an escape character (\) to let the formula know it shouldn't expect anymore values, and make the formula recursive, and leverage MAKEARRAY to extend prior created array by each new entry. Note that for references, the first reference must not cause an error, so needs to be non-blank.

```
ARRAY
=LAMBDA(val_1,
    LAMBDA(val_2,
        IF(
            TYPE(val_2)=16,val_1,
            ARRAY(
                MAKEARRAY(ROWS(val_1)+1,COLUMNS(val_1),
                    LAMBDA(i,j,
                        IFERROR(INDEX(val_1,i,j),val_2)
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    )
)
```

[image: ARRAY Examples]

Comment: That's pretty cool, and a partial answer/indirect answer is fine. So if A7 is blank, we get an error is that right? Why is that? Basically what does this mean: _"Note that for references, the first reference must not cause an error, so needs to be non-blank."_

Comment: Also why use TYPE() = 16 rather then ISERROR?

Comment: Sorry, should've tested a few more cases, =ARRAY(3)(A7)(A8)(3)("foo")("bar")(\) works for A7, A8 blank, so it's just if the very first entry is a blank reference; I'm not quite sure why, because TYPE(blank ref)=1 rather than 16; must be something going on in the Excel calc engine. And ISERROR seems to work just fine, just personal preference for TYPE.

Comment: I've made a slightly modified version of your function: `=LAMBDA(accumulator,LAMBDA([next_val], IF(ISOMITTED(next_val), accumulator, ARRAYBUILDER(ARRAYJOIN(accumulator,next_val)))))` where ARRAYJOIN is defined [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/268446/fancy-new-lambda-functions-with-variable-number-of-arguments-to-mimic-native-met#:~:text=(source)-,ARRAYJOIN,-Merge%20two%20arrays) as a function which flattens its inputs and puts one on the end of the other, works very similar to yours. Called as `ARRAYBUILDER(2)(A1:A5)()` note the `()` on the end to invoke the builder

Comment: ... I guess with this approach, you need either a special terminator value (IsOmitted for me, IsError for you) or a special continuation value- e.g. `ARRAYBUILDER(,1)(,2)(,3)(4)` miss the first optional argument to continue. I don't think you can get by another way except by providing the length, but if we have that then this whole thing is moot

Answer (score 1):

[`VSTACK`](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vstack-function-a4b86897-be0f-48fc-adca-fcc10d795a9c) now exists, which fulfils this role.

E.g.,

[image]

Comment: There are some clever older answers here but really this one ought to be the accepted answer. Note also the presence of the sibling function HSTACK.

Answer (score -1):

If `Array1` is defined as:

```
=CHOOSE(SEQUENCE(number_of_args), arg_1, arg_2, arg_3, ..., arg_n))
```

where `number_of_args` is such that `number_of_args >= n`, then your desired result is derived via:

```
=INDEX(Array1,SEQUENCE(SUM(1-ISERR(Arry1))))
```

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure how this fits in with the problem. I'm after a function to _create_ an array, not one to grab the first non-error elements from an existing array. Could you explain your answer a little more possibly?

Comment: Apologies if I misunderstood, but you stated "If I know the number of args, I can just use the choose function like this =CHOOSE(SEQUENCE(number_of_args), arg_1, arg_2, arg_3, ...))", so I created a version which works for an unknown number of args.

Comment: Oh I think I see where this is going. You mean I should have a function taking a load of optional args, store them in an oversized array then filter that array down using the isomitted function/iserr to return an array of valid values, is that the idea? If so, filtering is slightly slower than the binary search since it has to query every element I think, but syntactically a lot nicer, could be a one liner

Comment: No worries! Yeah, so what would the final ARRAY() function look like given that helper function?

Comment: Yes, that's the idea. Not efficient, of course, but perhaps you can put a sensible upper limit on number_of_args such that it doesn't result in too inefficient a set-up. I don't have LAMBDA, unfortunately - I presumed you would be able to adapt the construction I gave as required. Perhaps you prefer to see the full version: `=INDEX(CHOOSE(SEQUENCE(number_of_args), arg_1, arg_2, arg_3, ..., arg_n)),SEQUENCE(SUM(1-ISERR(CHOOSE(SEQUENCE(number_of_args), arg_1, arg_2, arg_3, ..., arg_n))))))`

Comment: Ah, no I thought you meant this: `=LAMBDA([arg_1],[arg_2], ..., [arg_n], LET(args, CHOOSE(SEQUENCE(n), arg_1, arg_2, ..., arg_n), FILTER(args, MAP(args, LAMBDA(arg, NOT(ISOMITTED(arg)))))))` to define an n-argument function and then filter it down - however the CHOOSE converts missing args to a default value of 0 which means `ISOMITTED` always returns `FALSE`. For your approach to work, I need to manually edit the value of `n` (as in add/remove args _from the formula_) to match number of args passed, at which point I could just fill in `number_of_args` manually. I want the new [optional] args.

Comment: ^ I think, unless I'm missing something - I may either be misunderstanding you or I didn't explain the original question clearly enough and so your answer isn't to the right question!

Comment: Apologies. Having reread I see now where I've misunderstood. Perhaps if zero were an inadmissible argument you could use `=LAMBDA([p_1],[p_2],...,[p_63],LET(MyArry,CHOOSE(SEQUENCE(63),p_1,p_2,...,p_63),FILTER(MyArry,MyArry<>0)))`