Multiple parameters in Lambda function in excel
In excel, is there a way to create Lambda Functions that can accept any number of parameters in the end?
Like TextJoin function, where the first two parameters are fixed and then from the third parameter, you can give any number of parameters.
If you could see TextJoin (or Sumifs) functions users can choose how many parameters to give.. Like they can give 3 texts to join or 5 text to join or N texts to join.  I need to write a lambda function that can accommodate parameters in that way.

You can go up to 253 parameters? It's a bit unclear what you're trying to achieve though.

If you could see Sumifs / TextJoin functions users can choose how many parameters to give.. Like they can give 3 texts to join or 5 text to join or N texts to join.  I need to write a lambda function that can accommodate parameters in that way.

But what's the end goal of your formula? There are probably some ways to do it. Most probably with VBA though.

@Excellor,  Thanks for your response.  I'm trying to understand how to handle such scenarios in Lambda functions.  I'm sure we can achieve this through VBA.

If you do something like =LAMBDA(x , SUM(x) ) you can select multiple cells. (edit: didn't see someone posted it as an answer already).

You are familiar with c#, why do you ask such question? You should understand everything which can be caused by this feature.

And having c# in background, you can create an Excel Add-In to extend the functionality per your needs.

Your explanation of your problem shows n ranges to join within TEXTJOIN. But TEXTJOIN has that ability by default, what's the use of writing a lambda for that? Do you mean something like here maybe? https://stackoverflow.com/a/78987409/12634230

Please make the question as concrete as possible. What is your goal, what is your current try, what did you expect from it, what does it do?

Hey @TheKing This answers your question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69319638/excel-function-to-construct-an-array-from-values-without-vba

The variable number of parameters, optional parameters, and default values are features supported by many programming languages. The optional parameters is only the feature supported by Excel for the LAMBDA function.
The simpliest way to provide the lambda with the variable number of parameters is to pass them as an array:
LAMBDA(a,SUM(a)) sums any number of values in the a array.
In most PLs this task is also can be resolved through methods overriding. Practically in Excel, you can define several functions Func1, Func2, Func3 etc. to cover all your needs.

LAMBDA allows to have optional parameters in this way:
OPTIONALSUM =LAMBDA(a,[b],IF(ISOMITTED(b),a+10,a+b))

where b is the optional parameter which can be not provided in the function call:
=OPTINALSUM(15)


25

Evidently, a few arguments at the end of the argument list can be optional:
OPTIONALSUM =LAMBDA(a,[b],[c],IF(ISOMITTED(b),a+10,IF(ISOMITTED(c),a+b+20,a+b+c)))

=OPTIONALSUM(15)


25

=OPTIONALSUM(15,3)


38


Sum does this without lambda. I think also the idea is to have the number of arguments be dynamical, so no different LAMBDAs for different count of arguments.

@P.b Sum is just for example here.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69319638/excel-function-to-construct-an-array-from-values-without-vba this is the type of thing, a lambda accepting dynamic args
