# Formatting text in messagebox excel Vba

Tags: vba, excel

I am new to Excel VBA and have written Vba code to loop through cells and get their values.After that do some processing and if it matches a certain criteria append them to a list with line break.
Do this until all rows are done. This works perfectly fine and end result is as image below:

[image]

The thing is i want the formatting to look neat , so is there a way that the gap in between the text is same on all rows so it looks neat.
The way i add the rows is :

```
          Dim tmpLine
          tmpLine = line & "      " & dateVal
          mainMessage = mainMessage & tmpLine & vbNewLine
```

Not sure if its the perfect way but that is what i know...

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I got this, maybe it'll solve your problem:

```
Sub msgBoxTest()

    MsgBox "inininegefedf" & vbTab & "1234" & vbCr & _
            "asdcainininegefedf" & vbTab & "1234" & vbCr & _
            "inininegefedf" & vbTab & "1234afsad", vbCritical

End Sub
```

Here is the result:

[image: Result]

Answer (score 3):

I've implemented a solution for this as complete as possible and spent a considerable effort for it. When transferring **clsFmsgBox**, **frmFmsgBox**, and **modFmsgBox** from [FmsgBox.xlsm](https://www.dropbox.com/s/kv4fzb8p5ov8etn/FmsgBox.xlsm?dl=0) Workbook the below code leads to [this kind of message box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SEiZE.png) may be managed with comparably little effort. The Workbook above provides coding examples as well.

```
 With cFmsgBox
    .Title = "Message Box supporting formatted text. Example 1"
    .Msg = "This is the first " & _
     .b("Test ") & "message spanning over several lines and paragraphs. The default margins, spaces, and font size had been used. " & _
                   "No need to say that the form width had been adjusted manually in order to have an optimum appearance." & _
     .Lf & _
     .Lf & "The formats " & _
     .b("bold") & ", " & _
     .u("underline") & ", and " & _
     .i("italic ") & "and may be combined with any of the colours " & _
     .b(.i(.u(.red("red")))) & ", " & _
     .b(.i(.u(.blue("blue")))) & ", and " & _
     .b(.i(.u(.green("green")))) & "." & _
     .Lf & .Lf & _
           "5 different links may be included in the message text, either in the full form like " & _
     .link("www.google.com") & " or with a friendly name like " & .link("www.google.com", "google.com") & ", which masks the url behind it." & _
     .Lf & _
     .Lf & _
        "Also it shows 2 of the 6 possible reply buttons and that they may contain any text. Since the number of lines is maximized to 3 their width will be adjusted " & _
        "automatically - but will remain the same for all buttons. The string returned by the display call is identical with the string of the clicked reply button."

    .Reply1 = "Click this reply to continue with the next example"
    .Reply2 = "Click this reply to finish with the Message Box solution's features"
    .Dsply 318

    If .Reply = .Reply1 Then Example2
End With
```

The message is displayed in a dedicated UserForm with dynamically created labels for each formated text string and dynamically created (up to 6) command buttons. The key to the formatted message are the format properties .b("xxx") for bold, .i("xxx") for italic and so on, which can all be nested like .b(.i("xxx")) to get an italic,bold text for example.

Alternatively, instead of a concatenaed string the message text may be provided with RTF/HTML like formating tags whereby the open/close Tag character defaults to {} but may as well be changed to <>. As an example:  "{b}bold{/b) {i}italic{/i}." will display: **bold** *italic*.

Answer (score 1):

Implement string.Format() - a bit overkill for just this one msgbox, but the reusability is quite endless:

[Implementing String.Format() in VB6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14534360/implementing-string-format-in-vb6)

Something like `msg = StringFormat("{0}\n{1,-10}{2:cMM/DD/YYYY}", msg, line, dateVal)` should work.

Or, focus on this part of the implementation:

```
alignmentPadding = Abs(CInt(alignmentSpecifier))
If CInt(alignmentSpecifier) < 0 Then
    'negative: left-justified alignment
    If alignmentPadding - Len(formattedValue) > 0 Then _
        formattedValue = formattedValue & _
            String$(alignmentPadding - Len(formattedValue), PADDING_CHAR)
Else
    'positive: right-justified alignment
    If alignmentPadding - Len(formattedValue) > 0 Then _
        formattedValue = String$(alignmentPadding - Len(formattedValue), PADDING_CHAR) & formattedValue
End If
```

Where `PADDING_CHAR` would be a " " whitespace and `alignmentSpecifier` the amount of padding you need.

In other words, pad `line` to 20 characters and then append the date:

```
tmpLine = line & String$(20 - Len(line), " ") & dateVal & vbNewline
```

..works for me:

```
?"'abc12" & string$(20-len("'abc12"), " ") & "12/12/2004"
'abc12              12/12/2004
?"'abc1234" & string$(20-len("'abc1234"), " ") & "12/12/2004"
'abc1234            12/12/2004
?"'abc1234456" & string$(20-len("'abc1234456"), " ") & "12/12/2004"
'abc1234456         12/12/2004
```

**UPDATE**

It seems the issue isn't about the message string itself, but because of the font used in `MsgBox`: what worked for me, worked because I used the *immediate pane* to get quick results, and that's displayed with a monospaced font (where all characters are same width).

[image: msgbox]

I suggest you create a quick form with a fixed-width `Label` that uses a font like "Courier New" or "Consolas"... or just display the date in front of the variable-length part.

Comment: My code is just 20 lines so i don't think it a good idea to add what you are suggesting...

Comment: i am not sure its working the last line ....or i might be not doing it rite but it gives the same result

Comment: yup did that , same result.

Comment: :) Thank you for taking time to do it.

Comment: why a ' before string does that matter?

Comment: No but I just put the result in a `MsgBox` and I see what you mean - I get the same result too; the monospace font of the *immediate pane* made it *seem* to work... Hmmm not sure there's a real fix, other than using a custom-made msgbox/form which uses a monospace font.

Comment: I think better to put Date in front than line !

Comment: Thank you for your help and you are rite changing font will work

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using a "userform". Under your VBA project in the VBA editor, right click and select "insert / userform" (or use top menu "insert / userform")

From there, you'll see a number of ActiveX controls in a "toolbox" (or click "view/toolbox") that can help you construct what you're after: sounds like you're after a "listbox", which you should find in the toolbox (hover over the items and "listbox" will appear as a tooltip)

With your listbox selected, you can set the number of columns plus the column widths in the "properties" window (click "view/properties window" if you can't see it)

See how you go, lots of good info on the web on VBA userforms and listboxes or happy to answer any more questions.

Cheers, Si

[EDIT] Just thought of some code I've got which should get you started (from a little tool I wrote to turn Office 2010 references in to Office 2003 references): in my main code module I've just got:

```vb
Sub FixReferences() 'Ctrl-Shift-F

    ufWorkbooks.Show

    If ufWorkbooks.blCancel = False Then
        With ufWorkbooks.lbWorkbooks
            For intindex = 0 To .ListCount - 1
                If .Selected(intindex) Then
                    SwapReferences Workbooks(.List(intindex))
                End If
            Next
        End With
    End If
End Sub
```

This loads my userform (called ufWorkbooks) in the line ufWorkbooks.Show. Execution passes to that form at this point: when execution comes back, a variable from the form is checked to see if cancel has been pushed, then you can see I've got a function running on each item of my listbox on the form called "lbWorkbooks". The code in my userform looks like this:

```vb
Public blCancel As Boolean

Private Sub cbCancel_Click()
    blCancel = True
    Me.Hide
End Sub

Private Sub cbOK_Click()
    Me.Hide
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Activate()
    blCancel = False

    FillWorkbooks
End Sub

Sub FillWorkbooks()
    Dim wbBook As Workbook

    lbWorkbooks.Clear

    For Each wbBook In Workbooks
        lbWorkbooks.AddItem wbBook.Name
    Next

End Sub
```

Here you can see I'm using different "events" to trigger certain bits of code. At the bottom you can see my "FillWorkbooks" sub is first clearing my listbox (which ive named lbWorkbooks) and then I'm adding items to it. This is good for one column listboxes. In your case, you might want to use .AddItem then .List(0, 1) = "whatever" (row 0 in the listbox, column 1). I can't remember if AddItem will add a blank row at the top for you to reference with .List(0... or if you'll need to add a counter .AddItem then .List(i...

Alternately you can use Listbox.ListFillRange to use a range of cells from your spreadsheet as the data source for your listbox.

Comment: I want to use message box. User open files this function runs and shows a box .... no listbox...

Comment: no worries. RetailCoder's answer looks good: I'd still recommend userform for anything more complicated though, let the native tools do the hard work for you ;)

Comment: @Simon As it turns out, if I had these exact requirements and needed to make these things line up, I'd create my own custom msgbox/userform. I'd use a label though, with a monospaced font to make sure "1", "0" and " " (space) have the same width so the thing *can* be lined up.

Comment: Plus a way to incorporate dynamic ASCII art :)