# VBA: How to get date as a string yyyy-mm-dd

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to get the Date as a string formatted `yyyy-mm-dd`.

I have tried various things with strange results:

```
Dim mydate As String
mydate = Date
mydate = Year(Date)
mydate = Month(Date)
mydate = Day(Date)
```

1. The first one gives `11/02/` without the year.

I can try to concatenate the data but:

2. The second gives the year OK
3. However the third gives month as 2 instead of 02
4. Similar for fourth.

Any clarification or an example would be very welcome.

Comment: Relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/q/14534360/1188513

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Use the `Format` function from the `VBA.Strings` built-in module:

```
Debug.Print Format(Now, "YYYY-MM-DD")
```

Comment: Perfect. Thank you very much !

Comment: With this I can output today -1 and with that get yesterday, now I wonder how can I do this with week nr? Debug.Print Format(Now - 1, "WW") dose not work (well it works but doesn't output current week, outputs next week that is why I add -1 but that doesn't do anything. , please if you can help me I appreciate it.

Comment: Sub find_week_number138()
Week_Num = WorksheetFunction.WeekNum(Now, vbSunday)
Debug.Print "Today’s week number is " & Week_Num
'still giving 18 which is wrong week number
End Sub

Answer (score 3):

```
Dim sToday As String
sToday = CStr(Date)
```

That gives sToday value, e.g. "2020-12-31", in the format of my system's date.

Answer (score 1):

In some VBA, the *Format()* function is not available. In this case, you can do it the old fashion:

```
y = cstr(year(now))
m = right("0" + cstr(month(now)),2)
d = right("0" + cstr(day(now)),2)   
mydate = y + "-"+ m + "-" + d
```