# VBA Full formula to cell

Tags: vba, excel

I've written this line of code to put this formula to cell T2:

```
Sheets("Output").Range("T2").Formula = _ 
     "=CONCATENATE(TEXT(C2;""MM/DD/JJJJ"");""-"";TEXT(S2;""MM/DD/JJJJ""))"
```

But I'm getting the following error:

> Run-time error '1004':
>   Application-defined or object-definded error

The formula is working if I copy-paste it, so I guess this is a syntax error.

Comment: What if you replace the `;` for `,`?

Comment: It works. Thanks for fast respond.

Comment: I added the answer to the post.

Comment: Please remember to mark he answer as correct, so that the question gets marked as answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct code:

```
Sheets("Output").Range("T2").Formula = _ 
     "=CONCATENATE(TEXT(C2,""MM/DD/JJJJ""),""-"",TEXT(S2,""MM/DD/JJJJ""))"
```

Comment: *Goes to regional settings, changes list separator character to a `|` pipe, breaks all VBA macros.*

Answer (score 3):

Excel uses the *list separator* character to delimit the parameters of a function.

Hard-coding a semicolon, or a comma for that matter, into your formula, makes your code vulnerable to changes in regional settings, as a hard-coded list separator character will stop working as soon as the Windows settings are modified, or if your code runs on a computer with different settings.

You can use some Win32 API to get the correct character from the regional settings, by adding this code in a standard module (.bas) that you can name `Win32`:

```
Option Explicit

Private Declare Function GetLocaleInfo Lib "kernel32" Alias "GetLocaleInfoA" _
    (ByVal Locale As Long, ByVal LCType As Long, ByVal lpLCData As String, ByVal cchData As Long) As Long

Private Declare Function GetUserDefaultLCID% Lib "kernel32" ()
Private Const LOCALE_SLIST = &HC

Public Function GetListSeparator() As String

    Dim ListSeparator As String
    Dim iRetVal1 As Long
    Dim iRetVal2 As Long
    Dim lpLCDataVar As String

    Dim Position As Integer
    Dim Locale As Long

    Locale = GetUserDefaultLCID()

    iRetVal1 = GetLocaleInfo(Locale, LOCALE_SLIST, lpLCDataVar, 0)

    ListSeparator = String$(iRetVal1, 0)

    iRetVal2 = GetLocaleInfo(Locale, LOCALE_SLIST, ListSeparator, iRetVal1)

    Position = InStr(ListSeparator, Chr$(0))
    If Position > 0 Then
        ListSeparator = Left$(ListSeparator, Position - 1)
    End If

    GetListSeparator = ListSeparator

End Function
```

(adapted from [this PCReview post](http://www.pcreview.co.uk/threads/get-list-separator-character-with-vba.2218762/))

The correct code would then be:

```
Dim separator As String
separator = Win32.GetListSeparator

Sheets("Output").Range("T2").Formula = _ 
    "=CONCATENATE(TEXT(C2" + separator + """MM/DD/JJJJ"")" + separator + """-""" + separator + "TEXT(S2" + separator + """MM/DD/JJJJ""))"
```

...which is utterly annoying. VBA needs a proper `StringFormat` method ([I made one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14534361/1188513)), so that you can do this:

```
Dim separator As String
separator = Win32.GetListSeparator

Dim formatString As String
formatString = "=CONCATENATE(TEXT(C2{0}\qMM/DD/JJJJ\q){0}\q-\q{0}TEXT(S2{0}\qMM/DD/JJJJ\q))"

Sheets("Output").Range("T2").Formula = StringFormat(formatString, separator)
```