# convert an integer variable to a string with leading zeros in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

For starters, there are LOTS of questions that have been asked with this topic.  However all the ones I kept clicking on were in languages other than VBA and I did not understand the syntax of those languages.

When I did a google search I found [this answer](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/7bb492d1-7079-46da-aaf5-14b39627b5eb/adding-leading-zeros-to-string?forum=vblanguage) which seemed promising.  AH FIDDLE STICKS!  I just realized that answer for VB and probably explains why its not working in my VBA

Situation

I have a variable called DimScale that is an integer.  I want to create a string called DimName that will start with "mm-" and be following by the integer from DimScale with leading 0s such that there are a minimum of characters after "mm-".

```
IF DimScale = 25
Then DimName = "mm-0025"

IF DimScale = 235
Then DimName = "mm-0235"

Note Dimscale >=1 and <= 9999
```

What I have tried

```
Dim Dimscale as Integer
Dim Dimension_Style_Name as String

String.Format("{0:0000}", DimScale)

Dimension_Style_Name = DimScale$
Dimension_Style_Name.Format("{0:0000}", DimScale)
```

I have read the gist too that Dimscale get converted to a string and then is sent through a loop of adding a leading zero until the length of the string equals the 4 characters in my case for the integer part.

I have also seen the case with IF statments where IF Dimscale <10 then "000"& If Dimscale <100 then "00"& etc.

Is there a way to do it like like the VB method in VBA?

Comment: You might want to peek at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14534361/1188513) if you want to be able to use the .NET `String.Format` syntax in VBA.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

maybe:

```
DimName = "mm-" & format(DimScale,"0000")
```

As per @MathieuGuindon valuable (as usual) contribution:

*Format (fully-qualified VBA.Strings.Format) takes a Variant parameter, and returns a Variant - you can also use its little brother Format$, which takes a String and returns a String, eliminating implicit conversions along the way*

Comment: I hate it when you are all around the answer, but just a few keystrokes off in the formatting!  Thanks for the quick response and I will accept as soon as it lets me

Comment: somebody had mercy on me

Comment: @ForwardEd, it happens to everybody here

Comment: Side note: `Format` (fully-qualified `VBA.Strings.Format`) takes a `Variant` parameter, and returns a `Variant` - you can also use its little brother `Format$`, which takes a `String` and returns a `String`, eliminating implicit conversions along the way.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon, thanks. I guess you were typing another page of your _book_ here.. But if you don't mind I'd add that in my answer (too few upovotes till now...).

Comment: @MathieuGuindon as a complete tangent. Rubberduck is the command I taught my dog to formally release her from whatever command she was following.  Was looking for something the general public would not guess.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon, _WTH_ I take a look at this _Rubberduck_ and ... how to exploit it?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar need to **apply leading zeros** *( 12 to 00012 )* to a specified range. But everything I'd found thus-far used an iterative cell-by-cell approach. I found an older but still valuable posting from SiddHarth Rout. His posting pertains to case conversion *( lower to upper case )* but I found it adapted nicely to applying leading zeros.

Here is link to SiddHarth's posting:
[Convert an entire range to uppercase without looping through all the cells](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19985895/convert-an-entire-range-to-uppercase-without-looping-through-all-the-cells)

[image: The need]

Here is the adaptation for applying leading zeros to a specified range:

```
Sub rngLeadingZeros(rng As Range, nbrZeros As Integer)
' Add leading zeros to a specified range.

    Dim strZeros As String
    Dim x As Integer

    'build string as required for text() function:
    For x = 1 To nbrZeros
        strZeros = strZeros & "0"
    Next

    'make sure the range is formatted as text:
    rng.NumberFormat = "@"
    
    'apply the format to the range:
    rng = Evaluate("index(text(" & rng.Address & ", """ & strZeros & """),)")

End Sub

Sub testZ()
    With ActiveSheet
        rngLeadingZeros .Range("e3:e9"), 5
    End With
End Sub
```

[image: The Result]

Comment: Sincere thanks for the assist.