# VBA Macro Returning Excel Formula result of "#VALUE" error instead of intended result

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I am attempting to write code that will add an input number of leading 0s to strings inside of the range currently selected by the user when the macro is run. I keep encountering errors where instead of returning the expected result, the evaluation of the formula is returning the #Value error and I honestly don't know where to start. I have looked into several solutions using the debugging assistance docs provided by Microsoft but I either don't understand the solution or it isn't there.

```
Sub Add_leading_00()

Dim rng As Range
Dim Area As Range
Dim leading_count As Long


leading_count = Application.InputBox(Prompt:="Enter an integer:", Type:=1)



  If Selection.Cells.Count = 1 Then
    Set rng = Selection
  Else
    Set rng = Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
  End If


  For Each Area In rng.Areas
    
Area.Value = Evaluate("Rept(0, " & leading_count & ")& & Area.Address & ")
  
  Next Area
  

End Sub
```

I do have a function that returns similar results but I have been unsuccessful in my attempts to call that function just on the range selected by the user at the time of the run, and that is necessary for the planned functionality of the macro.

```
Function AddLeadingZeroes(ref As Range, Length As Integer)

Dim i As Integer
Dim Result As String
Dim StrLen As Integer
StrLen = Len(ref)
For i = 1 To Length
If i <= StrLen Then
Result = Result & Mid(ref, i, 1)
Else
Result = "0" & Result
End If
Next i
AddLeadingZeroes = Result
End Function
```

There are several discussions on topics adjacent to this one as well that I have found and read through but I am not sure if they're relevant to my error or not. I suspect that I am missing something extremely simple.

[Leading 0s question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51899639/convert-an-integer-variable-to-a-string-with-leading-zeros-in-vba)

[text formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8265350/how-to-change-format-of-a-cell-to-text-using-vba?rq=1)

Comment: `Area.Value = Evaluate("Rept(0, " & leading_count & ")&" & Area.Address)`?

Comment: When I use this adjustment, instead of returning the error, it just does nothing. Progress, thanks!

Comment: After adding in a format adjustment to set it to text during the loop I was able to successfully return what I was looking for. THANK YOU!

Comment: Note that your quotes were off. `Area.Addess` was inside the quotes when it should be outside.

Comment: I realized that as soon as I read your comment. I knew it was something simple that I missed. Thanks again!