# Converting formula to string

Tags: vba

I have the following formula that I am inputting in a function.

```
dim minfee, feetier3, feetier4, feetier5, bpspread1, bpsread2, bpspread3 as double

call insformulaincell("=IF(K2 = 100, ""#NA"", IF(K2 <" & minfee & "," & feetier3 & ",IF(K2<" & feetier4 & ",K2+ " & bpspread1 & ",IF(K2<" & feetier5 & ",K2+ " & bpspread2 & ",K2+ " & bpspread3 & "))))")

'all the function does is paste the formula into a cell 
'How would I format the formula so that it can be stored as a single string?
'Ex:

dim sFormula as string 

sformula = ""=IF(K2 = 100, ""#NA"", IF(K2 <" & minfee & "," & feetier3 & ",IF(K2<" & feetier4 & ",K2+ " & bpspread1 & ",IF(K2<" & feetier5 & ",K2+ " & bpspread2 & ",K2+ " & bpspread3 & "))))""

call insformulaincell(sFormula)
```

The main issue is that the variables such as minfee would not reference its actual values but instead have the actual string variable name appear.

Ex: "... If(K2 <" & minfee & "," ... )
as opposed to 
"... If(K2 < 1) ..." ' assuming that minfee = 1

Comment: Remove the extra leading and trailing quote.

Comment: I tried that but it doesn't solve the main issue where the variable names no longer reference the variable values anymore

Answer (score 2):

In VBA `"` serves as a delimiter for *string literals*, like this:

```
Dim foo As String
foo = "some string"
```

If your string literal needs to contain `"` double quotes, you need to *escape* them, by doubling them up *between the string delimiters*:

```
foo = """some string"""
```

Printing the above would yield `"some string"`, *including* the double quotes.

So you *do* need to [remove the leading & trailing double quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54332282/converting-formula-to-string#comment95482641_54332282).

```
sformula = "=IF(K2 = 100, ""#NA"", IF(K2 <" & minfee & "," & feetier3 & ",IF(K2<" & feetier4 & ",K2+ " & bpspread1 & ",IF(K2<" & feetier5 & ",K2+ " & bpspread2 & ",K2+ " & bpspread3 & "))))"
```

Breaking this down, it's a concatenation of the following literals:

- `"=IF(K2 = 100, ""#NA"", IF(K2 <"` (note, `"#NA"` is a bad idea IMO. Use the `NA()` function to yield an actual worksheet error instead of a string value that *looks* like one)
- `","`
- `",IF(K2<"`
- `",K2+ "`
- `",IF(K2<"`
- `",K2+ "`
- `",K2+ "`
- `"))))"`

Which looks right to me.

Arguably, such concatenation is annoyingly confusing. A custom [StringFormat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14534360/implementing-string-format-in-vb6/14534361#14534361) function can help mitigate this, by abstracting away the concatenations:

```
sFormula = StringFormat("=IF(K2=100, ""#NA"", IF(K2<{0},{1},IF(K2<{2},K2+{3},IF(K2<{4},K2+{5},K2+{6}", _
    minfee, feetier3, feetier4, bpspread1, feetier5, bpspread2, bpspread3)
```