# Nested replaces in a "template" string

Tags: vb6

I'm trying to present some values to the user with an order dictated by a "template", if we can call it like that.

An example: Let's imagine that we have some variables called "ID/Name/Surname" of a person. And then, we have a template string like

```
"{Id}, {Name}{Surname}"
```

So the string shown would be "1, Max Power".
Or if we have a template string like

```
"{Surname}, {Name}"
```

We would have a result like "Power, Max".

What I have thought is doing it with nested replaces, like

```
Replace(Replace(Replace(templateString, "{Surname}", surname), "{Name}", name), "{Id}", id) //Being surname, name, and id variables
```

But there should be a better or better stylish way of doing that. How can I achieve this? Regular expressions?

Thanks.

Comment: I wonder if you are better off posting this on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: If you only have 3 parms, I think your approach is fine.  Obviously this is less than ideal when you have many parms.  You could also write this with 1 Replace statement per line.  Or you could get fancy and throw RegEx into the mix like with this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14534360/5162073).