Formatting a text file from Excel VBA
I already understand how to create a txt file using VBA, but I am struggling to output a string to this text file in a neat way. I want the output file to look as below:
Hello [input1]
This is [input2]
Thanks
[input3]
My assumption was the code might look something like this, but it fails as I am the VB editor expects the string to all be on one line:
Dim txtString As String
Dim input1 As String
Dim input2 As String
Dim input3 As String

Set input1 = Userform1.input1.Value
Set input2 = Userform1.input2.Value
Set input3 = Userform1.input3.Value

txtString = "Hello " & input1 & vbNewLine &
            "This is " & input2 & vbNewLine &
            & vbNewLine &
            & "Thanks" & vbNewLine &
            & input3
              

This is just an example. The actual output file will be 28 lines long, which is far too much to have in one line in one string in the VBA panel.
Does anyone have any idea how to make this look much tidied.
Thanks!

_ is the line continuation character, so "Hello " & input1 & vbNewLine & _ will stop the editor from being upset. Also remove the & at the start of the last three lines.

Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14534360/implementing-string-format-in-vb6.  This code should allow you to write


Note that you can have a maximum of 24 line continue characters, and there is also a size limit for one statement. Workaround: Start a new statement  txtString = txtString & ...
